# Variance failure in R markdown

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R, and at one point take the variance of six values (0.156, 0.128, 0.159, 0.171, 0.140, 0.157).  Running this code in the R console is fine--R spits out 0.0002341667.  However, when I run the same operation in Knitr to produce a PDF, I get the following error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.395 2.3416667\times
pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

If I take the square root, the error doesn't happen.  Any thoughts?  My code (excluding pulling from my source) is below.

```
values <- c(0.156, 0.128, 0.159, 0.171, 0.140, 0.157)
var(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please  add \usepackage[utf8]{inputnc} to the preamble of the tufte-handout.tex file in the rmarkdown package.
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/484d5b8e903e0e0c75c82f707efa35f9fd9a52b0